# Increasing Display resolution on Fedora 11

Tags: linux, virtualbox, resolution, fedora, fedora-11

I'm running Fedora 11 on a VirtualBox installed on Windows Vista machine.

I'm unable to increase the resolution on the virtual instance, the only available resolution on the Fedora instance are 640x480 or 800x600.

How do I increase my Display Resolution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you've installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Then, at least on a Mac OS X host, you can simply resize the window and the size will change in the guest OS. Or you should be able to access more sizes with the guest additions.

Answer (score 0):

How to change/improve the display resolution for a Linux Guest OS on Virtualbox: http://digitizor.com/?p=1808